# Rust chrono gives ParseError(NotEnough)

Tags: datetime, rust, datetime-format, rust-chrono

I am trying to parse a datetime string to `DateTime` object, but when I try this I am getting this ParseError. I don't understand what is going on, can someone help me out?

datetime string: `09-January-2018 12:00:00`

code: `let date = DateTime::parse_from_str(date.trim(), "%d-%B-%Y %T");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::DateTime;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", DateTime::parse_from_str("09-January-2018 12:00:00", "%d-%B-%Y %T").unwrap_err().description());
}
```

(https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9c0231ea189c589009a46308864dd9bc&version=stable)

gives more information:

```
"input is not enough for unique date and time"
```

Apparently, `DateTime` needs Timezone information, which you don't provide in your input. Using `NaiveDateTime` should work:

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::NaiveDateTime;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("09-January-2018 12:00:00", "%d-%B-%Y %T"));
}
```

(https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1acbae616c7f084a748e4f9cfaf1ef7f&version=stable)